# Writing JSON to file from browser

Tags: java, javascript, silverlight, applet

I'm working on a small web app type page designed to run in the decentralised environment [ZeroNet](https://github.com/HelloZeroNet/ZeroNet/) where there is no server, and any data is shipped around using torrents.

The project is a simple publishing platform. Zeronet serves downloaded content on localhost, so the web page does allow reading from JSON files that are alongside the file in JS.

However, using JS, I can't seem to find a way to write to external JSON files without having to ask the user every time. I've looked into [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) and [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/), but they persist JSON in memory, and I can't control the directory that they save to.

*So my question is*, is there a 'legitimate' (ie non-hack) way that I can save JSON files in a directory next to the page?
I'm pretty sure I'm going to have to do it in non-JS, maybe Silverlight or a Java applet, so that I can request the permissions once and once only. If there's a JS way, so much the better, but I don't want to have to ask the user every time.

Comment: Without explicit permission, JS is sandboxed away from the OS/file layer and with explicit, it's not cross compatible.   You're going to need another layer or use the baked in html5 storage containers.

Comment: When you say about explicit permission, can I request permissions to write to a part of the file system?

Comment: Sort of.  There's new implementations to JS, that let it do file stuff (read/write) but the user has to give it explicit permission.   Local storage is another newish tech but again cross compatible comes into play.

Comment: local storage is however not designed for storing files, but key-value pairs. As in: its main purpose is to store configuration data. Any other file API can only read, not write. And I kind of hope it stays that way. But you say this stuff runs on the localhost so the client and the server are one and the same machine? If so, forget javascript and do it with a server-sided technology.

Comment: I am thinking of trying it that way. I think the server is just a plain server at the moment, and doesn't allow the user to do anything more fancy than request data, but not being able to make use of server side technologies does seem a strange limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your json as a String in the localstorage. You have up to 10mb of space (Opera is unlimited I think). Also you can suggest the user to adjust the quotas in others Browsers.